# How to go to different page when I press back button on action bar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, back-button

I am trying to go to ProfileFragment page however when I try to press back button on action bar it goes LoginActivity which is another unrelated activity. How can I perform this?

Here is the code:
**My SettingsActivity.java**

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        Typeface ubuntu_MI = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Ubuntu-MI.ttf");

        // Get the ActionBar
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

        // Create a TextView programmatically.
        TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

        // Create a LayoutParams for TextView
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // Width of TextView
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // Height of TextView

        // Apply the layout parameters to TextView widget
        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

        // Set text to display in TextView
        // This will set the ActionBar title text
        tv.setText("Ayarlar");

        // Set the text color of TextView
        // This will change the ActionBar title text color
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF5EE"));

        // Center align the ActionBar title
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        // Set the serif font for TextView text
        // This will change ActionBar title text font
        tv.setTypeface(ubuntu_MI);

        // Underline the ActionBar title text
        // tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

        // Set the ActionBar title font size
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24);

        // Display a shadow around ActionBar title text
        //tv.setShadowLayer(
        //      1.f, // radius
        //    2.0f, // dx
        //  2.0f, // dy
        //  Color.parseColor("#FF8C00") // shadow color
        //);

        // Set the ActionBar display option
        ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        // Finally, set the newly created TextView as ActionBar custom view
        ab.setCustomView(tv);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        //Action Bar'daki back butonuna basınca ne yapacağını söylüyoruz.
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileFragment.class);
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    }
```

Comment: You can't create an Intent that leads to a Fragment, you can only navigate to Activities.

Comment: so, how can I fix this?

Comment: Create an Intent to the Activity that contains the ProfileFragment.

Comment: Did you host any fragment in your activity?

Comment: I have CombineFragment Activity which combines 2 different activities.One of them is StartingTestFragment, the other is ProfileFragment. In which page I will create Intent and how? because back button is in another activity which called SettingsActivity. I am trying to pass the page from SettingsActivity to ProfileFragment.

Comment: Can you show your full activity code?

Comment: edited my full activity code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an `Intent` that points to a `Fragment`. From `SettingsActivity`, you should create an `Intent` to go to your `CombineFragmentActivity` that hosts `ProfileFragment`.

Instead of writing

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileFragment.class);
```

You should write

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CombineFragmentActivity.class);
```

in your `onOptionsItemSelected` function.

Comment: Okay I got it but ı don't know how to do it in codes

Comment: how can I host ProfileFragment in CombineFragmentActivity?

Comment: This should help you - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: It didn't help me. What should I write in my CombineFragmentActivity?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about the Up Navigation. In that case you can declare a parent activity for your current activity and it will always take you there.

From Android Documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: Am I going to add this codes in AndroidManifest.xml right?

Comment: Yes. See the link for more detail.

Comment: I looked at the link and I saw this line: <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower --> I am working on 4.0.0 and upper

Comment: Just add it for backward compatibility, otherwise you can skip that part.